# Accessing Files from UNC Network Path in C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, unc

I have a desktop application in which the user is able to specify the input and output directories.Things work fine for local directories;but people have started complaining about network locations accessed using UNC Naming Conventions.

If the user pastes the UNC Path,the code checks if the Directory exists using the following method

```
if(Directory.Exists(selecteddir)
{
  // all good
}
```

This method returns false for some network locations situated on other machines.I have tested using default local machine UNC Path `\\?\C:\my_dir` and the code works fine.
The application runs with administrative rights .

Im new to accessing network locations in C# Code.Is there any specific way to do this? If the user has already performed windows based authentication for the UNC Shares,wont these shares be accessible by the c# application?

Please advice on how to go forward.

***Update:***

I have also tried using directory info

```
DirectoryInfo info1 = new DirectoryInfo(@textbox.Text);
if (info1.Exists)
 {
 return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this situation many times. In the end, I believe that there is some issue with `Directory.Exist` method and I leave it.

Now, I am using `DirectoryInfo` class to check that like this.

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"Your Path");
if (info.Exists)
{

}
```

It is working fine for now. So there are other reasons too but it works for me. And of course, it does not resolve the impersonation issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input.What exactly is the impersonation issue?

Comment: In the .NET, "Impersonation" means running your code under a specific user account.

Comment: okay.When a user attempts to access a network resource (using explorer),he will be prompted for the password right? If the person gets access to the resource by supplying the password,will that resource remain accessible to my c# application until he logs off ?

Comment: I think No because both are the separate thing, means If a person provides credential in UAC in explorer then that credential will not work within your application.

Comment: Have you encountered this issue? If yes,how did you manage to sort out this?

Comment: Actually, We are using UNC paths in our on-premises so such paths are accessible in the application as well as windows explorer. Still, we sometimes face this issue in case of network drop.

Comment: Good to know that.. Thanks

Comment: The issue still exists when using directoryinfo.